# what is the Id generation order in Javers for EntityDefinition with Multiple Id Properties

Tags: javers

I am using Javers with EntityDefinition like

```
EntityDefinitionBuilder.entityDefinition(MyObject.class).withIdPropertyNames("attr1","attr2","attr3").build()
```

I am getting cdoId as `"attr2,attr1,attr3"`

Is there any defined order of the attributes in cdoId creation?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it reflects the order of fields/getters in the class file.